# Cant get id from url php using $_GET / $_REQUEST methods

Tags: php

I cant get the ID from url using `$_GET/$_REQUEST` in php.

my link

```
http://localhost/Social/single.php?post_id=1
```

my code

```
function single_post() {

    if (isset($_REQUEST['post_id'])) {

        global $con;

        $get_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
        $get_posts = "SELECT * FROM posts (post_id) VALUES ('$get_id')";
        $run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$get_posts);

        if($run_posts) {
            echo "SUCCESS.";
        } else {
            echo "FAILED.";
        }
    }

}//singlepost ends here
```

It returns "FAILED". I have tried every other method I could find on internet.

Comment: Your issue isn't that you can't get the post_id, it's your select query that's invalid. **You should check your error log for error messages.** Also, you're wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Thank you Magnus. I tried changing my SELECT query. Its working now.

Comment: Please mark answers then, at least vote up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you are getting the id
but 
it gives you failed because you sql query is not correct

```
    $get_posts = "SELECT * FROM posts (post_id) VALUES ('$get_id')";
```

change it to something like

```
    $get_posts = "SELECT * FROM posts where post_id=$get_id";
```

if you are trying to fetch the post contents of that post_id

Answer (score 0):

SELECT query is should be written like

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id='$post_id'"
```